# MAC of VMNIC in vSphere for ESXi

Tags: networking, virtualization, vmware-esxi

How can I get the mac addresses for each `VMNIC` via vSphere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To view the MAC of a vNIC in a virtual machine, right click on the VM in the vSphere client, select "Edit Settings".  Select the Network Adapter in question from the hardware list.  The MAC will be displayed on the right hand side.

To view the MAC of a physical NIC on the host, select the host, go to the "Configuration" tab, and select "Network Adapters" from the list on the left.  This will give you all of the NICs installed on the host, along with MAC address and other information.

Comment: I might not have been entirely clear, but the VMNICs according to vSphere are the physical NICs on the host -- or at least, that is what I mean.

Comment: Ah, my mistake... I'll edit.